# Running multiple commands using trino python client - trino dbapi

Tags: python, trino

How can I  run multiple statments in trino python client?
https://github.com/trinodb/trino-python-client
Below is the sample code.

```
queries = filter(None, query.split(";"))
        for singelQuery in queries:
            cursor.execute(singelQuery)
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

Query

```
use test; select * from tbl
```

Getting below error

```
TrinoUserError(type=USER_ERROR, name=MISSING_SCHEMA_NAME, message="line 1:16: Schema must be specified when session schema is not set", query_id=20220908_082529_00009_uw5yi)
```

Answer (score 0):

for that specific error message you have to mention your catalog name and schema name :

```
use catalog.test;
```

If a catalog is not specified, the schema is resolved relative to the current catalog.

alternatively you can run your query like this , instead of using `use` :

```
select * from catalog_name.test.tbl;
```

for running multiple statements per query , you probably need to use trino cli , not sure iff python client support that,

```
>> trino client --file $filename
```

Comment: passing catalog while creating a connection.

` def __init__(self, username, trino_host, trino_port, trino_catalog):
        self.host              = trino_host
        self.port              = trino_port
        self.username          = username
        self.catalog           = trino_catalog`

Comment: need to use python client

Comment: Want to run same query as above. First Use and then Select

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I suggest you tackle this.  Just run the commands you want one after another (and note that the python client freaks out with the semicolon at the end of each SQL statement which is why mine don't have one).

code...

```
cur.execute('USE tpcds.tiny')

cur.execute('SHOW TABLES')
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
print('-------------------')
    
cur.execute('DESC promotion')
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
print('-------------------')
    
cur.execute('SELECT p_promo_id, p_channel_details FROM promotion')
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

output...

```
['call_center']
['catalog_page']
... rm'd some rows ...
['item']
['promotion']
['reason']
... rm'd some rows ...
['web_sales']
['web_site']
-------------------
['p_promo_sk', 'bigint', '', '']
['p_promo_id', 'char(16)', '', '']
['p_start_date_sk', 'bigint', '', '']
... rm'd some rows ...
['p_channel_demo', 'char(1)', '', '']
['p_channel_details', 'varchar(100)', '', '']
['p_purpose', 'char(15)', '', '']
['p_discount_active', 'char(1)', '', '']
-------------------
['AAAAAAAABAAAAAAA', 'Men will not say merely. Old, available ']
['AAAAAAAACAAAAAAA', 'So willing buildings coul']
['AAAAAAAADAAAAAAA', 'Companies shall not pr']
```